# How to pass string as a method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging

I have a method for logging:

```rb
def logger(text, level = 'info')

   tagged_logger = Logger.new("log/#{Rails.env}.log")

   tagged_logger.level "#{text}"

end
```

as you can see in the method, the `level` default value is `'info'`, but it can also be replaced with `'error'`, `'debug'`, `'fatal'` and `'unknown'`

the logger will work when I do it like this:

```rb
tagged_logger.info "#{text}"    # It will log with 'INFO' tag
```

But I want to put it in a method so I can use it anywhere. I want to call it like this:

```rb
logger("File not found!", 'error')
```

But I want to make the `level` in my method to be replace with `error`(not as a string). I want it to become like this:

```rb
tagger_logger.error "#{text}"
```

Can anyone help me please? Thanks :)

Comment: Search on `public_send`.

Comment: `tagger_logger.level.camelize.constantize "#{text}"` make sure you have already defined `Error` method.refer https://apidock.com/rails/String/constantize

Comment: Thanks for helping guys, but I found the method that I'm looking for. I approved it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use meta-programming (such as `send`) and risk calling unexpected methods. Instead, you can use the [`Logger#add`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html#method-i-add) method which already accepts a severity as its first argument.

In fact, the `Logger#info`, `Logger#error`, ... methods are just helper methods calling `Logger#add` under the hood.

If you get the message severity as a string, you can use `Logger::SEV_LABEL` to find the correct numeric severity value to pass to `Logger#add`

```
TAGGED_LOGGER = Logger.new("log/#{Rails.env}.log")

def logger(text, level = "info")
  severity = Logger::SEV_LABEL.find_index(level.upcase)
  raise ArgumentError, "Unknown log level #{level} given" unless severity

  TAGGED_LOGGER.add(severity, text)
end
```

Note that in the code, I used a globally defined Logger instance. This is generally good practice since creating a new Logger object (and thus opening the file anew) each time you are logging a single message is likely rather wasteful.

Comment: This worked too! but I cant put `Logger.new` outside of the method, because I'm using this method as a `ActiveSupport::Concern`. I just do something like `tagged_logger ||= Logger.new("log/#{Rails.env}.log")`
Thanks for the explanation btw!

Answer (score 1):

Using Ruby's [send](https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/send) method you can achieve this.

Try following,

```
def logger(text, level = 'info')

   tagged_logger = Logger.new("log/#{Rails.env}.log")

   tagged_logger.send(level, "#{text}")

end
```

Comment: Ahhhh, this is the method I was looking for! Thanks! It worked :D

Comment: Always use [`Object#public_send`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-public_send) instead of `send` when applicable.